# registro con campos opcionales codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

nombre
apellidao
*usuario
*contraseña
*email

Tengo un registro con campos opcionales, pero cuando hago un insert en la base de datos me da error porque estoy haciendo un insert del tipo:

```
INSERT INTO `usuario`(`nombre`, `apellido`, `usuario`, `contraseña`, `email`) VALUES (,, 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'email')
```

Haber si alguien sabe una solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilices las propiedades que ofrece el framework

**CONTROLLER**

```
function post_agregar()
{
   $nombre     = $this->input->post('nombre');
   $apellido   = $this->input->post('apellido');
   $usuario    = $this->input->post('usuario');
   $contrasena = $this->input->post('contrasena');
   $email      = $this->input->post('email');

   $data = array
   (
      'nombre'      => $nombre,
      'apellido'        => $apellido,
      'usuario'     => $usuario,
      'contrasena'  => $contrasena,
      'email'           => $email
   );

$add = $this->tu_modelo->nombre_de_tu_funcion($data);

if ($add == true) 
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('add','Se registro con exito!');
    redirect('tu_controlador', 'refresh');

}else {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No se ha podido guardar');
    redirect('tu_controlador', 'refresh');
}

}
```

**MODEL**

```
function nombre_de_tu_funcion($data = array())
{
    $this->db->insert('tu_tabla', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Con esto ingresas tus datos sin problemas.

**NOTA:** En la programación no puedes utilizar la "Ñ"

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que no puedes escribir varias comas seguidas sin contenido entre ellas.
Si los campos son opcionales, es decir te aceptan `null` como valor, debes de especificárselo si vas hacer la `query` como la has escrito, quedaría algo así:

```
INSERT INTO `usuario`(`nombre`, `apellido`, `usuario`, `contraseña`, `email`) VALUES (null,null, 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'email')
```